# how to hide a item in aci tree

Tags: jquery, angularjs, acitree

Is there anyway to use hide option during the construction of json in aci tree?

```
{
"id":1,
"label":"Brand",
"inode":true,
"checkbox":true,
"radio":false,
"branch":[{"id":2,"label":"Acura","inode":false,"checkbox":true,"radio":false,hide":true},{"id":3,"label":"Audi","inode":false,"checkbox":true,"radio":false}]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have searched the whole documentation and found no solution for adding a hide  option in aci-tree JSON construction. We can do via aci tree API handler as below:

```
$('#tree').on('acitree', function(event, api, item, eventName, options)
{
   if (eventName == 'init') 
   { 
        var firstItem = api.first();
        api.hide(firstItem);
   }
});
```

Note: As in documentation hidden[aciTreeHidden] node will be display:block; & 
background-color:#ccc;, so need to change to display:none in demo.css.